# When is the stabilizer of a partition normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group and $Ω$ a transitive (hence finite), faithful $G$-set, and let the author of this question be someone who only has a superficial understanding of permutation group theory.

Trying to motivate the definition of a block system, I've noticed that $G$ acts on the set of all partitions of $Ω$, which we will denote by $\DeclareMathOperator{Part}{Part}\Part(Ω)$.  I've noticed that block systems $ℬ\in \Part(Ω)$ precisely are the fixed points due to their $G$-invariance, i.e. $G_ℬ = G$.

Actually, I first noticed that the stabilizer of a block system is normal – so the following question seemed natural:

> **Question** when is $G_Π$ a nontrivial normal subgroup?

I even struggled with the simpler question:

> **Question** What is an example of $Π\in \Part(Ω)$ with $G_Π\unlhd G$?

Of course, this question becomes easy when we take $Π=\{\{x\}\mid x\in Ω\}$, which is stabilized only by $1$, so I'm asking for nontrivial stabilizers.
I've added the “transitive” restriction because we can always take a product action $G\times G'\curvearrowright Ω\times Ω'$ where we get such a scenario “for free” by taking orbits of one component, respectively; but I find that horribly uninsightful.

I looked at easy permutation groups such as $S_3$ or $D_4$ ($Ω=\underline{4}$) and nontrivial partitions, but couldn't find an example.

I'm aware of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/303748/91103), which tells us that if $G_Π$ is normal, then what stabilizes $Π$ also stabilizes $gΠ$, so I guess the “more transitive” the action $G\curvearrowright \Part(Ω)$ is, the heavier this restriction is, and the less such partitions exist.

Comment: Take $V_4 < G_4$ and the partition $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ for an exmple of $G_\Pi$ non-trivial normal.

Comment: That partition already is a block system, as it's stabilized by all of $G$, so this doesn't give any new information I'm afraid.

Comment: I see. You're right.